# Two-way SQL Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, distributed-computing, service-broker, sqlperformance

I'm trying to use SSB as full-duplex messaging infra for multiple distributed logical stations.
Several stations can reside on same process, or on different machines (doesn't matter).
The stations need to communicate and sync with each other by constantly sending messages back and forth.
The stations run as part of a Windows Service, so, a station's life-time is very long.
Each message a station sends may be designated to a single station or to multiple stations or to all stations (broadcast).
A message is relevant to a specific station only if it's designated to that specific station, or if it's a broadcast message.

All the SSB's Dialog/Converstation/Group terminology really got me confused.

I can't figure out how to determine who and when should become an Initiator/Target, because according to my case, each station can send a message whenever it needs to, and should receive relevant messages all the time.

Since many stations might send messages to many other stations, all at the same time, dequeuing time should be a quick as possible, and performance must be optimal.

[According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd576261(v=sql.100)#basic-optimization-techniques), I should use many conversations with many messages for optimal performance.
But I can't figure out when and how I should create a separate dialog/conversation, and when should a conversation end, if at all.

Can someone please shed some light on this, and give me a proper direction for my case?

Thank you.

Comment: IMHO, SB isn't the right tool for the job here because it does not natively support broadcast (pub/sub model); you'll need to do that in code (T-SQL or app). The consumer (initiator) creates the conversation with the implementing service (target). The conversation is implemented by separate queues for initiator and target messages. It seems at a minimum, each station is a SB service in your case and each station may be both initiator and target. What sort of message volumes are expected?.

Comment: Are the conversations two way? Or is it that for any two participants that either side can send a message to the other?

Comment: @DanGuzman At the moment, according to my testings, the maximum amount messages a single station might send in a second is 76 messages.

Comment: @BenThul I guess it's the latter, any station can send a message at any given time to any other station, or to multiple stations, or a broadcast message to all stations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each station has an inventory of all of the others (which may take some hand holding!), this should be doable.

In regards to the initiator/target terminology, whomever starts the conversation is the initiator and the recipients of that message are targets. Imagine the following real world conversation. I'll prepend any messages sent by initiator with an [I] and those sent by the target with a [T]

- [I] Hello department store. Tell me what kinds of socks you have for purchase.
- [T] We sell red, white, and blue socks.
- [I] I'll take two pairs of red socks.
- [T] Okay

In that case, there was only one target, but a given conversation can be initiated with multiple targets in mind (in your "multiple stations" or "broadcast" scenarios). To further the above analogy, it'd be akin to calling multiple stores at once and asking them all for their sock inventory.

Intuiting why you'd need to know who is the initiator and target, the above conversation could be broken down into the following message types: InventoryRequest, InventoryResponse, PurchaceRequest, PurchaseResponse. If you bundle those all into one contract, you should be off to the races.

Comment: So you say that the first station that wants to initiate a conversation should call BEGIN DIALOG?

In that case each station will call BEGIN DIALOG upon loading.

And since each station lives "forever", and constantly communicates with all other stations, should it's conversation live forever with it? Or would you consider "conversation" as a smaller time-frame?

Comment: It depends. Where I'm at now, I implemented a "conversations live forever" scheme as there is a cost to setting up a conversation. So, as a one-time operation, I set up the conversations and store the conversation handles in a table. When the application needs one, it grabs it from that table. That said, my implementation is admittedly weird. A more standard approach is what you're saying. Which is to do `BEGIN DIALOG` when you want to start a conversation, converse, and then one side issues an `END DIALOG` signaling that that topic is complete.

Comment: Ok. So I ended up having each station to create a new dialog upon load and a thread that constantly listens to that conversation handle for incoming messages.
I've also created a mapping table that maps each station's id to its conversation handle (inserted upon dialog creation).

Then whenever a station wants to send a message it can either send it to a specific station or to all stations, by looking up their id in the mapping table.

Comment: "a thread that constantly listens". Have you looked at Service Broker Activation (either internal or external)? Activation is part of the design of SB and prevents the "application sits in a tight loop waiting for messages" pattern.

Comment: Internal activation definitely doesn't fit my scenario, and I'm not sure external activation fits either.
I have a Windows Services running on multiple distributed machines. Each Windows Service contains multiple stations (as I described above), each of which listens to its own queue.

Calling an exe file with arguments as external activation, which then will have to route the activation event to the relevant station\s, seems like an over-kill to me, compared to running a polling thread in each station.

Do you think I'm wrong?

Comment: I don't know. For me, it depends on what happens at the target when a message arrives. Does it do some data change in the target database? If so, that's a classic internal activation scenario. Even if it's "the Windows service needs to do something once a message arrives", external activation makes sense. That said, if you've go something that works and isn't causing you trouble, keep doing what you're doing; the Service Broker Police aren't going to show up and make you change anything. :)